# How can I signal one thread to wait until a download is finished and after that pass the data to waiting thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a singleton class to download some data from the web. I am calling the download method of the singleton class from other class 'A' inside a GCD Queue and the downloads starts. The same time I am also executing this download method from a class 'B' in a GCD Queue. In this situation I want to inform the Class 'B' to wait until the download is completed. And when the download is completed give a copy of the downloaded data to class 'B' also. Here I am trying to download the same file from two classes A and B, otherwise there is no problem in my implementation. How is it possible?

Means here I am calling the same method in different threads. So how can I signal the thread B that the same file download is in progress in thread A and when finished pass the data to thread B also

```
- (NSData *)Download:(NSString *)urlString{

     // here I am doing all the downloading operations
     return data;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downloader.h

```
// Signature of a block that is called with the downloaded data from a URL
// when the download is complete
typedef (void)(^)(NSData *) DownloadCompletedBlock;

// Public interface of a class that downloads data from URLs
// Downloads take place on a private dispatch queue, which
// downloads URLs one at a time
// Previously downloaded URLs are cached in a dictionary
// Every so often the cache should be processed to discard old
// entries. This will stop the cache from growing too large.
// Since all downloads happen on the same dispatch queue,
// accesses to the cache are naturally serialized without the need
// for a lock
@interface Downloader : NSObject

// Download the contents of a URL
// When the download is complete downloadCompleted will
// be executed on the callbackQueue to pass the downloaded
// data as a result
// This is the method that thread A should call
- (void)download:(NSString *)URLString 
    calbackQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)callbackQueue
 completionBlock:(DownloadCompletedBlock)downloadCompleted;

// Download the contents of a URL blocking the thread that calls the
// method
- (NSData *)downloadBlocking:(NSString *)URLString;

@end
```

Downloader.m

```
// Private implementation interface
@interface Downloader ()

// The thread/queue on which all downloads take place
@property (readwrite, atomic) dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue;
// A cache of previously downloaded URLs
@property (readwrite, atomic) NSMutableDictionary *cachedDownloads;

// Download the contents of a URL and cache them
- (NSData *)downloadAndCacheUrl:(NSString *)URLString;

@end

// Implementation
@implementation Downloader

// Create the download queue and cache
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloadQueue", NULL);
    self.cachedDownloads = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  }
  return self;
}

// Download the URL aynchronously on the download queue.
// When the download completes pass the result to the callback queue
// by calling downloadCompleted on the callback queue
- (void)download:(NSString *)URLString 
    calbackQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)callbackQueue
 completionBlock:(DownloadCompletedBlock)downloadCompleted {
  dispatch_async(self.downloadQueue, ^{
    NSData *downloadedData = [self downloadAndCacheUrl:URLString];
    dispatch_async(callbackQueue, ^{
      downloadCompleted(downloadedData);
    });
  });
}

// Download the data blocking the calling thread
// Use a block variable to store the result
// Since the downloaded data is immutable, we do not need
// to worry about synchronizing it or copying it
// Use dispatch_sync to wait until the result is available
// If the data is already in the cache because thread A downloaded it
// then the cached data is used.
// Since downloads happen serially, there is only ever one download happening
// at a time so the download will only happen once
- (NSData *)downloadBlocking:(NSString *)URLString {
  __block NSData *downloadedData = nil;
  dispatch_sync(self.downloadQueue, ^{
    downloadedData = [self downloadAndCacheUrl:URLString];
  });
  return downloadedData;
}

// Download the content of a URL. If the data has already been
// downloaded and cached, then use the cached value
- (NSData *)downloadAndCacheUrl:(NSString *)URLString {
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:*)URLString];
  NSData *downloadedData = [self.cachedDownloads objectForKey:URL];
  if (downloadedData) {
    return downloadedData;
  }
  downloadedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
  if (downloadedData) {
    [self.cachedDownloads setObject:downloadedData forKey:URL];
  }
}

@end
```

Hope this is clear enough