# pause for-loop in objective-c. possible?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

may sound like a stupid question, but, out of curiosity, is it possible to pause a for loop in objective c?

for example:

```
for (NSManagedObject *a in sortedArray)
{
  //do something that takes time, for example download something
}
```

in the above example the for loop would start all downloads at the same time, because after starting the download (or whatever action you put there) it would go to the next object in the array. what if i would like to wait till the download is finished? is there a way to pause the download or would i have to restart the for loop skipping the already downloaded ones?

Comment: Hope you are doing it on background thread..

Comment: i am not doing it at all, its just one of those things that  need from time to time and could be handy to know if it can be done and how to do it correctly!

Comment: You can download synchronously in the loop, the the loop will be blocked during the download, but it's not recommended. You can download everything what you want asynchronously.

Comment: And if you insist on doing it synchronously (a possible use case is when you need to download the items in a fixed order), just do it in a different thread, not blocking the UI. Asynchronous method is the best method though..

Comment: is it possible to have a very simple example posted as answer? maybe of both solutions? so future people know the answer too! i think this might be a useful question for many

Comment: There are many examples available for asynchronous downloading with a simple search. Putting code here just for general information isn't going to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. One way would be using Grand Central Dispatch semaphores. Read about dispatch semaphores here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-18-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-iv-odds-and-ends.html.

Also check this question on SO, might be exactly what you need: [How can I signal one thread to wait until a download is finished and after that pass the data to waiting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397601/how-can-i-signal-one-thread-to-wait-until-a-download-is-finished-and-after-that)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSThreads / GCD for multiple processes.

But you will have to deal with synchronous and asynchronous methods and sometimes with there call backs.